# Data Table not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery Data Table plugin, and I need to sort the table by first column, which is a Date object, but it does not sorting correctly. My table is render as shown below.

[image]

My JavaScript code:

```
var table = $(".dataTable").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 15, 
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing":   "Processando...",
            "sLengthMenu":   "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":  "Não foram encontrados resultados",
            "sInfo":         "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty":    "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",
            "sInfoPostFix":  "",
            "sSearch":       "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":          "",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "Primeiro",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sNext":     "Seguinte",
                "sLast":     "Último"
            }
        },
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bPaginate": true
    });

table.fnSort( [ [0,'desc'] ] );
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: do you see any error on "inspect element" when you click sort?

Comment: There's no error in my browser console when I click sort and it's keeping sorting wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first date in the list is not in the same format as the others. It has the day first instead of the month.

Comment: It's Brazilian date format, I need tell to plugin what format I want to use?

Comment: Your data isn't all in the same format. The table is sorting according to the numbers it is given, and it may also be setup to sort according to US standards. Check to see if you can change the date format and/or make sure your data is entered correctly.

Comment: If I format in US standards works perfectly, like this `<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" />`, so I added a hidden column in US standard and other column in Brazilian format, and tell to sort by first column (US standards) and the all others columns following the sorting. Thanks for help.